# Как в Symfony записать на диск значение, доступное всем сеансам?

Tags: symfony, кэширование

Нужно записать на диск значение, доступное всем сеансам.
Есть ли какие-то стандартные средства типа Laravel-евского кэша. Если нет - в какую папку посоветуете записывать файл со значением?

Comment: а другого кэша никакого нет? redis,memcached,apcu

Comment: Я понял из документации Симфони, что они кэшируют действия, а не значения.